# How to use lodash filter?

Tags: html, angularjs

I have three dropdowns:-

```
<form name="myForm" data-ng-submit="save(myForm.$valid)"novalidate="novalidate">
    <label>1st</label>
      <select ng-model="a.value[0]">
          <option value="One">One</option>
          <option value="Two">Two</option>
          <option value="Three">Three</option>
      </select>
     <label>2nd</label>
     <select ng-model="a.value[1]">
          <option value="One">One</option>
          <option value="Two">Two</option>
          <option value="Three">Three</option>                            
     </select>
    <label>3rd</label>
      <select ng-model="a.value[2]">
         <option value="One">One</option>
         <option value="Two">Two</option>
         <option value="Three">Three</option> 
      </select>

     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-save"></i>
           Save</button>
   </form>
```

What I want is user select unique value in each dropdown, if not get notified.

```
$scope.a.value = [];
 scope.func = function () {  
if (_.uniq(scope.a.value).length !== scope.a.value.length) {
scope.notify("error", "Please set unique values");
 }
};
```

I used the above code but didn't get it right? Please tell me what I am doing wrong? or give me a possible solution.

Also what I want is that it is not saved if the values are not unique. What validation should I apply and where?

Comment: you probably wanted yo use `!=` instead of `==`

Comment: no that didn't work either

Comment: Do you have any error in console?

Comment: no error in console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ng-change="uniqCheck()"` in each select directive:

```
        <select ng-model="a.value[0]" ng-change="uniqCheck()">
            <option value="One">One</option>
            <option value="Two">Two</option>
            <option value="Three">Three</option>
        </select>
```

Use in the controller:

```
    $scope.uniqCheck = function(){
        $log.log('this is $scope.a', $scope.a);
        if (_.uniq($scope.a.value).length !== $scope.a.value.length) {
            // $scope.notify("error", "Please set unique values");
            $window.alert("error - Please set unique values")
        }
    }
```

this should work as @Selva.K comment

Comment: your solution is showing alert even they are unique values

Comment: By Uniq did you mean if in first drop down the user selected one he has to select the same in other ?

Comment: no if in first he select one, in second two and in third three then also I get error

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work fine - `_.uniq` returns an array with duplicate values removed - so if you compare the length of the result of `_.uniq` with the result of the unmodified array you can determine if the values are all unique.

The step you're missing is that you are not calling your validation - as pointed out by Anandapriyan S.D.

You need to make sure that every time you change your select you call the function that checks the uniqueness.

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <label>1st</label>
    <select ng-model="a.value[0]" ng-change="uniqCheck()">
      <option value="One">One</option>
      <option value="Two">Two</option>
      <option value="Three">Three</option>
    </select>
    <label>2nd</label>
    <select ng-model="a.value[1]" ng-change="uniqCheck()">
      <option value="One">One</option>
      <option value="Two">Two</option>
      <option value="Three">Three</option>
    </select>
    <label>3rd</label>
    <select ng-model="a.value[2]" ng-change="uniqCheck()">
      <option value="One">One</option>
      <option value="Two">Two</option>
      <option value="Three">Three</option>
    </select>
  </div>


function Ctrl($scope) {
  // not sure why you are nesting values onto a, unless a has more important information 
  // you could just use $scope.a = []; and then use $scope.a[0] ...
  $scope.a = {};
  $scope.a.value = [];
  $scope.notify = function(error, message) {
    alert(error + ': ' + message);
  }
  $scope.uniqCheck = function() {
    if (_.uniq($scope.a.value).length !== $scope.a.value.length) {
      $scope.notify("error", "Please set unique values");
    }
  };
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/UARPwYWQGjJux9FrQwFc?p=preview

Comment: Yes you should.